# How to call mysql function in snowflake UDF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write below UDF in snowflake.But it doesnt allow to use sql functions like TO_DATE,DATE_ADD,dayofweek . Any alternative idea would be helpful. Thanks.

````
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getShippingDate(deliveryDate varchar,deliveryCountryCode varchar, holidayList varchar,deliveryDays varchar) 
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$

    deliveryPeriod = 0
    weekDay = 0
    deliveryDate= TO_DATE(deliveryDate)

    if(deliveryCountryCode != 'IN') {
        deliveryPeriod = 2
    }
    else {
        deliveryPeriod = deliveryDays + 1
    }   

    if(deliveryPeriod <= 0) {
        deliveryPeriod = 1
    }

    /* substract delivery period from delivery date */
    deliveryDate = DATEADD(Day ,-deliveryPeriod, to_date(deliveryDate))  

    weekDay = dayofweek(deliveryDate) 

    /* if shipping date falls on sunday then substract 2 days */
    if (weekDay == 0) {
         deliveryDate =  DATEADD(Day ,-2, to_date(deliveryDate)) 
     }    
    /* if shipping date falls on saturday then substract 1 days */ 
    if(weekDay == 6){
        deliveryDate = DATEADD(Day ,-1, to_date(deliveryDate)) 
    }

    /* check if shipping date falls on holiday then substract 1 */
    if(charindex(deliveryDate , holidayList) > 0) {
        deliveryDate = DATEADD(Day ,-1, to_date(deliveryDate)) 
    }
    return deliveryDate
$$```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively easy to create date functions in JavaScript.  Look at example below.
Just remember:

1. Please use the `DATE` SQL datatype for input and output
2. Parameters must be "Quoted" if you want to reference them in MixedCase
3. Use a semicolon `;` to terminate each statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getShippingDate("deliveryDate" DATE, "offset" FLOAT) 
RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
  function day_add(dt, days) {
    return new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + offset);
  }
  return day_add(deliveryDate, offset);
$$;
SELECT getShippingDate(CURRENT_DATE, -2);
```

`new Date()` does some magic when you add or subtract outside the days of the month.

Comment: By the way, SQL `DATE_FROM_PARTS()` does the same magic as `new Date`, eg,  `DATE_FROM_PARTS(year, 1, 0)` gets you New Year's Eve from the year before.

Comment: Hi Hans, Amazing thank you. I saw that but i wasn't able to use that in snowflake, i haven't seen that kind of example in snowflake documentation. Thank you for your idea and I got something new to learn.

Comment: You're welcome, examples in the docs are somewhat on the thin side.  I've ended up experimenting with parameters for about everything, and it is time consuming.  But sometimes rewarding.

Comment: My example with `DATE_FROM_PARTS()` was also on the thin side.  The function has similar properties as `DATEADD()`. Month and day parameters can be any number.  Eg. in `DATE_FROM_PARTS(2019, 13, 32)` both month and day overflows, and you end up with `2020-02-01`.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing your function as a scalar SQL UDF would solve the problem in this case.  Or you could implement your own javascript date math.  [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date).  The good news is that you can call JS UDFs from your SQL UDFs.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to try like below:

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_test()
  returns VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$
    snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: "SET dt = DATEADD(MONTH, 1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"} ).execute();
    return 'success';
  $$
  ;

-- CALL ds_work.ddd.usp_test()

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i want the same in UDF so that i can use the same in my select query. It is of course possible in stored procedures.